# Azure Cache for Redis - Redis database persistence with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've configured with terraform, Redis Database persistence(RDB) on Azure. According to official documentation, it should be stored on Premium storage account. Backup creation somehow works. Every 15 minutes I am getting a new backup.
I tried to check if backup is working and tried to import exported data into the same Azure Redis Cache. Unfortunately I am receiving following error
[Redis cache RDB import failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6jZn.png)
*"The request to import data into cache 'Name' failed with status 'error' and error 'One of the SAS URIs provided could not be used for the following reason: The data contained within the selected blob cannot be imported because it is not in a supported format. Please select a blob in the Redis RDB file format. As an example, a blob that was exported from a premium tier instance would be in the correct format"*

This is how snapshots look like from storage account. Naming is generated automatically.
[Backup from storage account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4twHa.png)

When I tried to do manually export, I've saved the filed with extension name.rdb and data import worked.

Configuration I am using:
Storage account

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "dev" {
  access_tier                       = "Hot"
  account_kind                      = "StorageV2"
  account_replication_type          = "LRS"
  account_tier                      = "Premium"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public   = false
  cross_tenant_replication_enabled  = false
  default_to_oauth_authentication   = false
  enable_https_traffic_only         = true
  infrastructure_encryption_enabled = false
  is_hns_enabled                    = false
  location                          = local.location
  min_tls_version                   = "TLS1_2"
  name                              = "Name"
  nfsv3_enabled                     = false
  public_network_access_enabled     = true
  queue_encryption_key_type         = "Service"
  resource_group_name               = local.resource_group_name.dev
  sftp_enabled                      = false
  shared_access_key_enabled         = true
  table_encryption_key_type         = "Service"
  tags                              = local.tags
  blob_properties {
    change_feed_enabled      = false
    last_access_time_enabled = false
    versioning_enabled       = false
  }
}
```

Redis

```
module "redis_for_test_purposes" {
  source              = "Somewhere"
  name                = "Name"
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name.dev
  location            = local.location
  tags                = local.tags

  sku_name      = "Premium"
  family        = "P"
  capacity      = 1
  redis_version = 6
  redis_configuration = {
    enable_authentication         = true,
    rdb_backup_enabled            = true
    rdb_backup_frequency          = 15
    rdb_backup_max_snapshot_count = 1
    rdb_storage_connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.dev.primary_connection_string
  }
}
```

Is there a possibility to set naming for a RDB backup with terraform?
Maybe I've configured something wrongly?

Generated backup with terraform, tried to import exported data with terraform and it failed with error above.
After that generated backup manually. Exported data with naming name.rdb, imported it into the same azure redis cache and it worked.

I do expect to terraform code to be working and backup generated by terraform working fine